# Must cdk bootstrapping be done by a User with admin access?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am setting up a CDK application such that it can be deployed to multiple AWS accounts (dev and prod). The prod account was bootstrapped a few weeks ago by another developer but is working as expected by using a User called `CDKDeployUser` in a Group called `CDKDeployUsers` with attached Policy `CDKDeployPolicy`. The policy used (which works for all day to day CDK-related functions in the prod account) is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/cdk-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I set up the dev account, I created a precisely identical User, Group, Policy and tried to run `cdk bootstrap` but I got errors about being able to assume a `cdk-*` related Role that didn't exist yet in the newly created account. I assumed that Cloudformation would create these roles as it did in the prod account but again, I don't know exactly how that account was bootstrapped.

In order to "just make it work", I added an Administrator policy to the `CDKDeployUsers` Group and ran `cdk bootstrap` and of course the bootstrap *did* create the necessary role that couldn't be used before.

**So, is it a known thing that bootstrapping must be done by an administrator even though subsequent CDK actions can be performed with far fewer permissions?**

I can't find it documented anywhere. It seems crazy that the expectation is for us to add an Admin policy every time we need to bootstrap (or upgrade the bootstrap templates as of CDK v2) and then detach them afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

So I've been looking into the same issue and had to essentially just run through the errors `cdk bootstrap` would spit out whilst progressively adding the permissions to the role.
*Really annoying/cumbersome process, as you've said I really wish AWS would publish the permissions even if only for the default bootstrap configuration.*

I've managed to come to the following role/permissions configuration that successfully bootstrapped the account for me.

There's potentially some improvements to be made with scoping more specifically to resources but hopefully this will help you in your endeavours.

I've been using CDK version `2.20.0` which is on [v12 of the bootstrap template](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v2.20.0/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-template.yaml).

If using a different version of the template it's entirely possible some of these permissions are not required. For example I initially was testing with a version on `v10` and found `ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy` was not needed with that version.

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:{account number}:stack/CDKToolkit/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:UntagRole",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:TagRole",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:TagPolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:UntagPolicy",
                "iam:UpdateRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::{account number}:policy/*",
                "arn:aws:iam::{account number}:role/cdk-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cdk-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:PutParameter",
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:{account number}:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:*:{account number}:repository/cdk-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CreateRepository"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Hope this helps you.

*edit: added `"cloudformation:GetTemplate"` as I just found out it's required for re-running bootstrap against an already bootstrapped account -.-*

Comment: Thanks for this @naffers - huge help. FYI: I also needed to add: `"s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration"` (CDK 2.83.1)

Comment: FYI my solution in the end was just to temporarily grant admin to my CDK user to bootstrap. Then I immediately revoke admin and substitute my existing CDKDeployPolicy policy, which works for all CDK operations except for bootstrapping.