# Backup vault creation failed because of insufficient privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-backup

I am trying to create a backup plan, rule and vault using AWS CDK. After deploying the application I receive the following error in cloudformation console.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Insufficient privileges to perform this action. (Service: Backup, Status Code: 403, Request ID: xxxxxxx)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

My CDK bootstrap role definitely have access to *backup*. See policy document below.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "cdk",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:*",
        "logs:*",
        "serverlessrepo:*",
        "servicediscovery:*",
        "ssm:*",
        "cloudformation:*",
        "kms:*",
        "iam:*",
        "sns:*",
        "dynamodb:*",
        "codepipeline:*",
        "cloudwatch:*",
        "events:*",
        "acm:*",
        "sqs:*",
        "backup:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Following are my CDK code snippets:

**backup-rule**

```
ruleName: 'myTestRuleName',
completionWindow: Duration.hours(1),
startWindow: Duration.hours(1),
scheduleExpression: events.Schedule.cron({
    day: '*',
    hour: '2'
}),
deleteAfter: Duration.days(90),
```

**backup-vault**
I tried without encryptionKey and also with a key that I have created through AWS backup web interface. None worked

```
new backup.BackupVault(this, `${id}-instance`, {
    backupVaultName: props.backupVaultName,
    // encryptionKey: this.key
})
```

**backup-plan**

```
new BackupPlan(scope, `${id}-instance`, {
      backupPlanName: context.backupPlanName,
      backupPlanRules: context.backupPlanRules,
      // backupVault: context.backupVault
 });
```

**backup selection**
I also tried without creating the role and letting AWS CDK create and use the default role.
NOTE: I have also tried created plan, rule and vault without resource selection to make sure, that the problem does not occur on the *resource selection* side.

```
const role = new iam.Role(this, 'Backup Access Role', { assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('backup.amazonaws.com') });
const managedPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyArn(this, 'AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup', 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup');
role.addManagedPolicy(managedPolicy);
plan.backupPlan.addSelection('selection',
      {
        resources: [
          BackupResource.fromDynamoDbTable(MyTable)
        ],
        //role: role
      }
)
``
```

Comment: check this post for cdk permissions https://stackoverflow.com/a/72397104/13126651

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem too and adding permissions for `backup-storage` solved it for me! Referenced the AWSBackupFullAccess permissions

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you put a note where to find this option.

Comment: Although I am an administrator on the console, I still face this error even if I add to my permissions: "backup-storage:*"