# AWS CDK execution role policy recommendation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, identity-management, assume-role

My Ci/CD pipeline authenticates with AWS via OIDC and to perform `cdk` operations I need to assume role with sufficient credentials

I do not want this role to have `AdministratorAccess` policy

But can't find any recommendation re aws-predefined policies or custom policies should be used for CDK

CDK creates bunch of roles during initialization, maybe I need only allow to assume them?

The same time I cannot create policy to allow assume all `cdk-*` roles as wildcards are not supported in `Principal` - can you please provide any recommendations?

Comment: It is VERY difficult to create restrictive policies, e.g. CDK might need to create a role for Lambda to run and ensuring *that* role has only very limited access is difficult to impossible. This is *especially* true for CDK (vs. bare CFN) due to the large amount of custom resources it relies on, and therefore the lambdas underneath.

Comment: For granting permission to assume the cdk roles, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118082/what-iam-permissions-are-needed-to-use-cdk-deploy) might help.